# blender loop cut tab doesnt appear

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

[image]

[image]

Hi someone knows how can I extend that tab that is cuted? and I cant change the values of the loop cut. thanks

Comment: Hello, what tab is cut? To change the loopcut number, use MMB or + and - of the number keys

Comment: Presumably the bottom-left adjustment one as shown! Useful if you want to add a particular number of loop cuts and only appears _after_ you've clicked or pressed Return to complete the loop so you can't then use MMB or  + - keys. I've never seen that cutoff effect here.