# Empty drop-down menu after upgrade to 4.0

Tags: interface

[image]

So I downloaded Blender 3.6 from the website since Steam auto-updating my Blender to 4.0 and [PolyQuilt](https://github.com/sakana3/PolyQuilt) add on doens't work on 4.0, but then I got this menu bug? How do I fix this?

Comment: Is this bug generally happening or just with the Polyquilt addon? Because I don't see this bug in my 4.0, and Polyquilt wasn't updated for a long time and Blender changed a lot inbetween.

Comment: I've seen this mentioned before [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/304628/blender-loop-cut-tab-doesnt-appear) a couple of days ago but have no idea whether the questioner sorted the problem or what could cause it.

Comment: Starting with your normal Blender startup, it might be worth turning off the toolbar ('T' key), Saving as a startup file (File > Defaults), restarting Blender, then turning it on again. Similarly try toggling Region Overlap under Preferences > Interface > Editors and restarting in case something has got corrupted in the settings file.