# Operator menu appears as micro dropdown but can't expand it to see options

Tags: interface

my Operator Panel does appear in lower left corner, but it's width has somehow shrunk and does not respond (meaningfully) to clicks, click-and-drag, right-click, etc..
[image: operator panel is too small]

Left clicking only toggles the menu arrow from pointing right to pointing down (as depicted). Neither state allows me to expand it to see items.
I've tried editing Interface preferences >> resolution scale AND I've even tried Edit>Preferences>hamburger menu> Load Factory Preferences but there's no change in appearance. Please Help!

- Blender 3.6.5 on Windows 11

Comment: Hard to say but your whole UI in Blender seems overscaled. go to preferences -> interface and try to adjust resolution scale and see if that helps you

Comment: Mentioned at least 5 times before here, so far with no definite resolution. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/305257/how-can-i-expand-the-operator-panel and others...

Comment: Is there any chance this file was saved in Blender 4.0 and then opened in this version?