# Can't bring back the "menu back" to its original state

Tags: interface

I am having trouble finding out how to bring back the "menu back" pop up, from when you finish an action in the viewport. It randomly happened after adding an add-on.

I am using blender 3.6.5.

This is what it looks like:
[image]

and what it should look like:
[image]

what can I do to solve this?

Comment: Is it still like that if you load the factory settings?(https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/preferences/introduction.html#prefs-menu)

Comment: I've tried that initially and nothing had changed, I tried googling numerous times as well and nothing. After some digging on other posts when I went into the interface tag, I read a few others may have that problem. A user "Jade", mentioned using properties tab & switching it to the viewport, which worked: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/305257/how-can-i-expand-the-operator-panel It only happened with this one specific file. (I didn't know about their issues prior posting this problem)

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have seen this issue posted here 2 or 3 times, and each time it was mentioned to be a bug. It might have been fixed in the newer releases, you could try Blender v3.6.7 or 4.02. Also perhaps check your graphics drivers is up to date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose this can be a broken UI layout saved in the Blend file.

So try this:

1. Use *File* → *New* → *General* to open a default scene with default layout. If UI is ok, proceed to the next step.
2. When load the file from the blender file browser (*File* → *Open*), uncheck the **Load UI** checkbox, which is on the left-hand side in the toolbar, to ignore the layout in the file to be loaded:

[image]

This will keep the UI of the *current file*.

This issue may occur then you open and save a blend file in older versions that it was saved.

Comment: Thank you! I used this on all the files that had this problem, and the menu shows up properly even re-opening the files after saving. It's less of a hassle to re-organize everything compared to the other solution. Thanks so much.